# Python GUI only shows one label instead of two

Tags: python, user-interface

So I'm making a game and I was wondering why the num of rows/columns show one instead of showing both. When I comment one out, the other shows and vice versa instead of both showing.

```
class OthelloGUI():

    def __init__(self):

        self._root_window = tkinter.Tk()

        self._root_window.title('Othello')

        self.read_row()

        self.read_column()


    def read_row(self) -> int:


        self.row_text =tkinter.StringVar()

        self.row_text.set('Num of rows:')

        row_label = tkinter.Label(
                master = self._root_window, textvariable = self.row_text,
                background = 'yellow', height = 1, width = 10, font = DEFAULT_FONT)

        row_label.grid(row=1, column = 0, padx = 10, pady=10, sticky = tkinter.W+tkinter.N)

        return self.row.get()


    def read_column(self) -> int:

        self.column_text =tkinter.StringVar()

        self.column_text.set('Num of columns:')

        column_label = tkinter.Label(
                master = self._root_window, textvariable = self.column_text,
                background = 'yellow', height = 1, width = 13, font = DEFAULT_FONT)

        column_label.grid(row=1, column = 0, padx = 10, pady=50, sticky = tkinter.W+tkinter.N)

        return self.column.get()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `grid` with the same coordinates:

```
row_label.grid(row=1, column = 0, padx = 10, pady=10, sticky = tkinter.W+tkinter.N)

column_label.grid(row=1, column = 0, padx = 10, pady=50, sticky = tkinter.W+tkinter.N)
```

When you grid both at (1, 0), the second one will override the first. Instead, use different row/column arguments:

```
row_label.grid(row=1, column = 0, padx = 10, pady=10, sticky = tkinter.W+tkinter.N)

column_label.grid(row=2, column = 0, padx = 10, pady=50, sticky = tkinter.W+tkinter.N)
```

Of course, set the row/column to whatever you want in your interface.

Comment: Oh I have a new question. I'm adding optionmenus under the read_row, but it says optionmenu isn't defined.   `      option = OptionMenu(self.root_window,self.row, 4,6,8,10,12,14,16)

        option.grid(row=1, column = 1, padx=10, pady = 10, sticky = tkinter.E+tkinter.N)
        return self.row.get() `

Comment: @accelerate You should generally make another post for a new question. Regardless, I can try to answer it – you seemed to have imported `tkinter`, so try using `tkinter.OptionMenu` instead of just `OptionMenu`.